# Renew vault Postgres Backend credentials

Tags: spring-vault

How do I renew spring vault Postgres Backend credentials using  SecretLeaseContainer ?

@override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

```
final RequestedSecret secret = RequestedSecret.renewable("postgres/creds/readonly");

leaseContainer.addLeaseListener(new LeaseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLeaseEvent(SecretLeaseEvent secretLeaseEvent) {


    if (secretLeaseEvent instanceof LeaseExpiredEvent) {

                          ????

    }

    }
});

leaseContainer.addRequestedSecret(secret);
```

}